# Import external text file to ppt text box

Tags: vba, powerpoint

For instance, when we'd like to copy text from notepad or something to PowerPoint for font decoration which could be used such as movie subtitle. When we find "enter" in the text, we'd like to create new text box in PowerPoint. So, the number of the text box of the ppt should be the same as the number of lines in the text file.

Ex) pls ignore when it confused you..
In notepad :
aaa bb (enter)
cc ddd ee (enter)

### In ppt :

### l  aaa bb   l

---

### l  cc ddd ee   l

Comment: Plenty of posts here on how to read a text file using VBA.

Comment: Do you need a new text box for each line of text in the text file, or would it work to have it create one text box with a new paragraph for each line of text in the text file? That would be quite simple, and would just need a few formatting touchups to finalize.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the responses!
Let me reply your comments.

@Steve Rindsberg, I meant earlier one i.e. ''a new text box for each line of text in the text file''.

@Tim Williams, I know some but I was not sure those are for PowerPoint or for Excel.